# How do I code a tiny drawer to open when the user hits the ellipses?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a row where there is an ellipses button that means "more options". When the user clicks this, I want to show a tiny drawer with 2 buttons that appears right next to the ellipses. I'm not sure how to get started though. I think this might be the way to go, but I'm just guessing. The other options I've seen is to use a `Drawer()` wrapped with a `Container()` to make it tiny, but when I put that in my `onTap` function it says that `Drawer()` can't be used because I can't assign the type `Drawer` to parameter type `void Function()`. So I guess this means I need to do something like the below where I create my own function and feed it to the `onTap`, right?

```
GestureDetector(
   child: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
   onTap: moreOptions(),
),


void moreOptions() {
  //Open the tiny drawer and show "Remove friend" and "Block" options, which will each open a dialog box when pressed
  //Close the tiny drawer?
}
```

Comment: Might be easier to make use of PopupMenuButton and PopupMenuItem and see if you can format the child of PopupMenuItem to appear as you want.

Answer (score 0):

A drawer size can be controlled using a Container or a SizedBox. To open and close a drawer when a button is clicked (dynamically), you must first declare and initialize a scaffold Key. You can then use the openDrawer and openEndDrawer functions to open and close a drawer. Example code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  void moreOptions() {
    if (_scaffoldKey.currentState?.isDrawerOpen == true) {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState?.openEndDrawer();
    } else {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: SizedBox(
        //height: your_preferred_height,
        //width: your_preferred_width,
        child: Drawer(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              //your buttons come here
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
        onTap: () => moreOptions(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```